# How to use the BCELoss in PyTorch?

Tags: torch, autoencoder, loss, pytorch

I want to write a simple autoencoder in PyTorch and use [BCELoss](http://pytorch.org/docs/nn.html#torch.nn.BCELoss), however, I get NaN out, since it expects the targets to be between 0 and 1. Could someone post a simple use case of BCELoss?

Comment: https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/vae/main.py#L80-L85

Comment: Have you added the sigmoid function for the last layer in your network?

Comment: no, the last layer has no activation.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### Update

The `BCELoss` function did not use to be numerically stable. See this issue https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/751. However, this issue has been resolved with [Pull #1792](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/1792), so that `BCELoss` is numerically stable now!

---

#### Old answer

If you build PyTorch from source, you can use the numerically stable function `BCEWithLogitsLoss`(contributed in https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/1792), which takes logits as input.

Otherwise, you can use the following function (contributed by yzgao in the above issue):

```
class StableBCELoss(nn.modules.Module):
       def __init__(self):
             super(StableBCELoss, self).__init__()
       def forward(self, input, target):
             neg_abs = - input.abs()
             loss = input.clamp(min=0) - input * target + (1 + neg_abs.exp()).log()
             return loss.mean()
```

Answer (score 5):

You might want to use a sigmoid layer at the end of the network. In that way the number would represent probabilities. Also make sure that the targets are binary numbers. If you post your complete code we might help more.